# Set or display browser tab name

Tags: browser, tabs

I have a site I'm trying to have the page title display on the tab within IE and Firefox.

I have the title set but when I go to view the site the tabs just show the URL of the page.

I searched and was unable to find a clear answer on how to correct this issue.

Is this a browser issue?  I want it to be clear to my users what page they are on.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue.  I had a title tag in the head of my master page which was causing the title to be blank and the url to display in the tab.  After removing it now my titles appear.